# Fixed header fadeIn on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, html, zurb-foundation

I have an issue on my website in that there are two mysterious divs creeping into my HTML code, and I'm not really sure why.

I think it's the use of data-magellan-expedition="fixed" in the (poorly named *sorry*) #navigation block. Would really appriciate someone taking a look and giving me some pointers and how this could be fixed?

[Website](http://www.carlosrios.co.uk)

All relevant code is pasted velow.

I'm using the below javascript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var offset = 200; // some offset value for which when the header becomes hidden
  $(window).scroll(function() { 
    if($('#navigation').is(':visible') && $(window).scrollTop() < offset) {
      $('#navigation').fadeOut(100);
    } else if(!$('#navigation').is(':visible') && $(window).scrollTop() > offset) {
      $('#navigation').fadeIn(400);
    }    
  });
});
```

This is the css:

```
#navigation {
  display: none;
  background-color:rgba(27, 28, 29, 1);
  height: 70px;
}

.logo {
  margin: -10px 0;
}
.nav {
  li {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    font-family: 'Arvo', cursive;
    color: $primary-color;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  li:hover {
    color: $secondary-color;
  }
}


.nav .active{
  color: $secondary-color;
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
   <div class="hide-for-small-only removeDivs">
      <div id="navigation" data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="medium-3 columns text-center">
            <div class="logo">
              <h1>
                <a title="#" href="#top">
                 <img src="#" alt="#" />
                </a>
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <nav>
            <div class="medium-9 columns">
              <ul class="nav right inline-list">
                <li data-magellan-arrival="home" data-slide="1">Link1</li>
                <li data-magellan-arrival="services" data-slide="2">Link2</li>
                <li data-magellan-arrival="potfolio" data-slide="3">Link3</li>
                <li data-magellan-arrival="contact" data-slide="4">Link4</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now for some reason, somewhere along the line the below two divs are being rendered:

[image]

Which nudges the content when you begin to scroll and the js effect comes into effect at the offset point.

currently the below css has fixed it.

```
removeDivs div:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none!important;
  height: 0!important;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is causing this? I'm using Foundation 5.

Many thanks.

Comment: fiddle fiddle fiddle...

Comment: I use Foundation 5 but without a fiddle or live example it's hard to see what you mean.

Comment: This is the [website](http://www.carlosrios.co.uk)
You can see the code there. I appreciate your help, thank you.